# What optimization techniques are applied to Rust code that sums up a simple arithmetic sequence?

Tags: c, rust, llvm-codegen

The code is naive:

```rust
use std::time;

fn main() {
    const NUM_LOOP: u64 = std::u64::MAX;
    let mut sum = 0u64;
    let now = time::Instant::now();
    for i in 0..NUM_LOOP {
        sum += i;
    }
    let d = now.elapsed();
    println!("{}", sum);
    println!("loop: {}.{:09}s", d.as_secs(), d.subsec_nanos());
}
```

The output is:

```
$ ./test.rs.out
9223372036854775809
loop: 0.000000060s
$ ./test.rs.out
9223372036854775809
loop: 0.000000052s
$ ./test.rs.out
9223372036854775809
loop: 0.000000045s
$ ./test.rs.out
9223372036854775809
loop: 0.000000041s
$ ./test.rs.out
9223372036854775809
loop: 0.000000046s
$ ./test.rs.out
9223372036854775809
loop: 0.000000047s
$ ./test.rs.out
9223372036854775809
loop: 0.000000045s
```

The program almost ends immediately. I also wrote an equivalent code in C using for loop, but it ran for a long time. I'm wondering what makes the Rust code so fast.

The C code:

```c
#include <stdint.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

double time_elapse(struct timespec start) {
    struct timespec now;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &now);
    return now.tv_sec - start.tv_sec +
           (now.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec) / 1000000000.;
}

int main() {
    const uint64_t NUM_LOOP = 18446744073709551615u;
    uint64_t sum = 0;
    struct timespec now;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &now);

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_LOOP; ++i) {
        sum += i;
    }

    double t = time_elapse(now);
    printf("value of sum is: %llu\n", sum);
    printf("time elapse is: %lf sec\n", t);

    return 0;
}
```

The Rust code is compiled using `-O` and the C code is compiled using `-O3`. The C code is running so slow that it hasn't stopped yet.

After fixing the bug found by visibleman and Sandeep, both programs were printing the same number in almost no time. I tried to reduce `NUM_LOOP` by one, results seemed reasonable considering an overflow. Moreover, with `NUM_LOOP = 1000000000`, both programs will not have overflow and produce correct answers in no time. What optimizations are used here? I know we can use simple equations like `(0 + NUM_LOOP - 1) * NUM_LOOP / 2` to compute the result, but I don't think such computations are done by the compilers with an overflow case...

Comment: Besides `-O3` it's worth adding `-Wall -Wextra`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your Rust code (without the prints and timing) compiles down to ([On Godbolt](https://rust.godbolt.org/z/rHSIgC)):

```
movabs rax, -9223372036854775807
ret
```

LLVM just const-folds the whole function and calculates the final value for you.

Let's make the upper limit dynamic (non constant) to avoid this aggressive constant folding:

```rust
pub fn foo(num: u64) -> u64 {
    let mut sum = 0u64;
    for i in 0..num {
        sum += i;
    }

    sum
}
```

This results in ([Godbolt](https://rust.godbolt.org/z/FJ_IPH)):

```
  test rdi, rdi            ; if num == 0
  je .LBB0_1               ; jump to .LBB0_1
  lea rax, [rdi - 1]       ; sum = num - 1
  lea rcx, [rdi - 2]       ; rcx = num - 2
  mul rcx                  ; sum = sum * rcx
  shld rdx, rax, 63        ; rdx = sum / 2
  lea rax, [rdx + rdi]     ; sum = rdx + num
  add rax, -1              ; sum -= 1
  ret
.LBB0_1:
  xor eax, eax             ; sum = 0
  ret
```

As you can see that optimizer understood that you summed all numbers from 0 to `num` and replaced your loop with a constant formula: `((num - 1) * (num - 2)) / 2 + num - 1`. As for the example above: the optimizer probably first optimized the code into this constant formula and did constant folding then.

#### Additional notes

- The two other answers already point out your bug in the C program. When fixed, `clang` [generates exactly the same assembly](https://godbolt.org/z/EGodoe) (unsurprisingly). However, GCC doesn't seem to know about this optimization and [generates pretty much the assembly you would expect (a loop)](https://godbolt.org/z/1MlqBE).
- In Rust, an easier and more idiomatic way to write your code would be `(0..num).sum()`. Despite this using more layers of abstractions (namely, iterators), the compiler generates exactly the same code as above.
- To print a `Duration` in Rust, you can use the `{:?}` format specifier. `println!("{:.2?}", d);` prints the duration in the most fitting unit with a precision of 2. That's a fine way to print the time for almost all kinds of benchmarks.

Answer (score 7):

Since an `int` can never be as big as your `NUM_LOOP`, the program will loop eternally.

```
const uint64_t NUM_LOOP = 18446744073709551615u;

for (int i = 0; i < NUM_LOOP; ++i) { // Change this to an uint64_t
```

If you fix the int bug, the compiler will optimize away these loops in both cases.

Comment: Sorry, forgot that part. Really appreciate your help. I have another question: if the compiler optimized away the loops, where do the programs get the numbers? Both programs are printing the same number, and I tried to reduce NUM_LOOP by one and the result is 9223372036854775811 from both programs. Considering the overflow, it makes sense. If the loops are optimized out, how can we get the numbers? I also tried NUM_LOOP=1000000000, which will not produce an overflow, and results from both programs are 499999999500000000 in almost no time. How can the programs do that?

Comment: Actually, I was planning to update my answer.  The loop can be expressed arithmetically in constant time. And compilers are smart enough to do this.  However I tested earlier, and the results are not clear cut on if this optimisation takes place, it depends on compiler version  and the value of the NUM_LOOP constant.

Answer (score 5):

Your code is stuck in an infinite loop.

The comparison `i < NUM_LOOP` will always return true since `int i` will wrap around before reaching `NUM_LOOP`